# How to find critical points for local extrema?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The function $$y=\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)\sqrt {x+6}$$ has a local maximum at $x=-4$, and local minima  at $x=6$ and $x=-6$. I was wondering how I could find those three critical points. The first derivative doesn't give me enough insight. Is there any way I could find them without looking at the graph?

Comment: $x=-6$ is boundary of definition domain, it is almost always local minimum or maximum. Other points should fit $y'=0$. Just take first derivative and try to factorize it.

Comment: Maybe my derivative is wrong, but still I don't find where -4 and 6 are coming from. Any tip please?

Comment: The sign of $y''$ show the point, which is root of $y'$ is local minima or maxima.

Comment: @joe: Show me how are you taking derivative. You should get several summands, then you should reduce them to common denominator to add, then you should factor numerator, that should give $(x-6)(x+4)$.

Comment: OK, I got $y'=0.5(x+6)^{-0.5}+\frac{(x+6)^{-0.5}}{x}-\frac{2\sqrt{x+6}}{x^2}$, which does not give anything like -4 or 6. Even $y"$ doesn't seem to imply those numbers. Am I missing something here?

Comment: $y'$ is correct. Common denominator is $A=2x^2\sqrt{x+6}$. $y'=(Ay')/A$. Calculate $Ay'$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu, Great thanks alot!